# I've just downloaded Ubuntu, How can I install it?

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I have just download the Ubuntu and now don't know what to do. How can I install it. It does not seem to do anything

Comment: Hello. Please update your question with at least WHAT you downloaded. And 2nd: this is NOT Windows. Please use Ubuntu Software Center as your source for usable software if it is not Ubuntu itself you downloaded. If it is Ubuntu: you need to burn a cd/dvd with the ISO you downloaded and reboot with the CD/DVD in your drive.

Comment: @Rinzwind don't forget usb drive! I haven't used a cd in like 5 years now...

Comment: just follow the instructions on http://ubuntu.com/download

Comment: @Callum - please look at this Q&As and add to your question what you have tried: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callum, was it Ubuntu 12.04 you downloaded?? If it was, the next thing to do is to burn the file (filetype "iso") on to a CD or a DVD. You can use a Windows CD/DVD burner for this. When you have got that far, come back and make a comment and we'll tell you what to do next. Good luck.

Comment: Great stuff!! Let us know when you got the CD burned. OK??

Comment: After burning i understood what to do but thank you for helping.

Comment: 8th May: Well done Callum, now just remember to come back here as often as you can and then you can help others with this same problem. That will be a feather in your cap!!

Answer (score 0):

all the installation guides for dok snd disks for any system are here in the ubuntu site:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Don't assume it is Ubuntu he downloaded ;)

Comment: I did download ubuntu but not of a cd